# Responsive changes in ngx-bootstrap carousal

Tags: html, angular, bootstrap-4, carousel, ngx-bootstrap

i am learning angular and facing issue while making site responsive in ngx-bootstrap carousal. Is it possible to do responsive changes in ngx-bootstrap carousal?

On main view I am showing 3 images per view and I want to show just 1 image in mobile view.
Here I am sharing my code.

Code in testimonials.component.html

```
<carousel [itemsPerSlide]="itemsPerSlide" [singleSlideOffset]="singleSlideOffset" [interval]="false" [noWrap]="noWrap">
    <slide>
        <img src="../../../assets/images/user1.png">
    </slide>
    <slide>
        <img src="../../../assets/images/user1.png">
    </slide>
    <slide>
        <img src="../../../assets/images/user1.png">
    </slide>
    <slide>
        <img src="../../../assets/images/user1.png">
    </slide>
    <slide>
        <img src="../../../assets/images/user1.png">
    </slide>
    <slide>
        <img src="../../../assets/images/user1.png">
    </slide>
</carousel>
```

Code in testimonials.component.ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-testimonials',
    templateUrl: './testimonials.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./testimonials.component.scss']
})
export class TestimonialsComponent implements OnInit {
    itemsPerSlide = 3;
    singleSlideOffset = false;
    noWrap = false;
    slidesChangeMessage = '';
    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit(): void {
    }
}
```

Comment: So, in mobile you just want to show one image, this is, no carousel at all? In desktop you want to have a carousel sliding 3 images and on mobile just one? Or what Im missing?

Comment: No in carousal I want to display one image in the mobile view.

Comment: But a carousel is supposed to show only one image at the time and then slide to a new one. Your current issue is that is showing more than one image? Can you create a codepen/jsfiddle whatever where I can see your issue in live? Or add a screenshot? Thanks!

Comment: I am using "Multilist Start From Index" slider from this link https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/carousel. Here you can see multiple images can be added in any carousel.. Also this is stackBitz demo link: https://stackblitz.com/run

Comment: Got it now, thanks! Will have a look ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After investigating this for a while, I came up with a solution that I believe would suit you.

What you need to take into consideration is that it **doesn't listen for changes on the screen width**.

This means, the value of `itemsPerSlide` is set on `ngInit` method and never updated again (as it wasn't required on your question). When you load the page with a device under 480px, it shows one image on the slider, if it's bigger, it shows 3.

You can change the breakpoint changing the value on the private property `mobileBreakpoint`.

Let's have a look at how your example will look like:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-testimonials',
    templateUrl: './testimonials.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./testimonials.component.scss']
})
export class TestimonialsComponent implements OnInit {
    itemsPerSlide = 3;
    singleSlideOffset = false;
    noWrap = false;
    slidesChangeMessage = '';

    private innerWidth: number;
    private mobileBreakpoint = 480;

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit(): void {
      this.adjustsItemsPerSlide();
    }

  private adjustsItemsPerSlide() {
    this.innerWidth = window.innerWidth;
    if (this.innerWidth < this.mobileBreakpoint) {
      this.itemsPerSlide = 1;
    } else {
      this.itemsPerSlide = 3;
    }
  }
}
```

- `private innerWidth: number;` holds the current viewport width. Use to decide which number of `itemsPerSlide` will be used.
- `private mobileBreakpoint = 480;` holds the breakpoint, at which point we will be using 3 or 1 slide.
- `private adjustsItemsPerSlide`: this method will read the current viewport width and apply different values on `this.itemsPerSlide`.

I also create an [example on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-evxxa9?file=app%2Fngx-bootstrap-demo.component.ts) that shows the desired effect.

PS: if you are using universal, this won't work, and you will need to inject a windowsService instead of using the windows object (which is native browser windows object, not angular service) straight in the component.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Hey! thanks. this works fine. But can we apply the same code for window resize?

Comment: Hi back @HardiShah, I just spent few hours debugging this issue, and after reviewing the implementation: https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/blob/development/src/carousel/carousel.component.ts I can't find a way of making this react to width changes. I can add an observable on windows resize, but no public API allows me to change the number of itemsPerSlide. This needs to be addressed on their repo and a feature must be added. With this in mind, not much I can do to make it respond to windows resize. This want on your original question neither :) What do you think? Good enough?

Comment: I also created an issue on their repo to see if we can fix this there. https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/issues/5723

The big issue here is that most of their apis are private and not accesible :)

Comment: You are welcomed, but did you cancel the bounty? If so, why? I think thats not fair to me as I was actively working on your issue to help and get the bounty!

Comment: No, i didn't cancel the bounty. I guess you are awarded with the bounty. Why should I cancel the bounty if someone is spending some time to help me out?